# how can i differentiate between big and small letter in java

Tags: java, arrays, arr, letter

i need to set a new array with 10 characters in which contains 2 capital letters. I need to find the capital letters and replace them with the same SMALL letters. how can i do it? how can i differentiate between small/capital letter?

Comment: char, big letters?? can you explain a little bit more with an example??

Comment: Please post your attempt at this.

Comment: im sorry my english is bad. for example : afgKertMh should be afgKERTMh

Answer (score 0):

To convert some letter to small/capital letter

```
  public class Convert
  { 
 public static void main (String args[]){
 char array[]={'a','f','G','K','e','R','t','M','h','j' };
    System.out.print(Character.toUpperCase(array[8]));//to convert h to  H...for example
    System.out.print(Character.toLowerCase(array[2]));//to convert G to g...for example

} }
```

If you want to know weather the letter is small/capital letter... Its outputs in boolean

```
public class Differentiate
{ 
public static void main (String args[]){
char array[]={'a','f','G','K','e','R','t','M','h','j' };
    System.out.print(Character.isUpperCase(array[8]));//false because h is small letter ...for example
    System.out.print(Character.isLowerCase(array[0]));//true because a is small letter ...for example

} }
```

but i dont know you want converting or differentiate !!

Comment: Please note that the official documentation for Character.toUpperCase says "In general, String.toUpperCase() should be used to map characters to uppercase. String case mapping methods have several benefits over Character case mapping methods. String case mapping methods can perform locale-sensitive mappings, context-sensitive mappings, and 1:M character mappings, whereas the Character case mapping methods cannot."